# Unable to recognize colon in String C++

Tags: c++, string

This snippet of code include the string I want to display and a helper method that's sole function is to display the string, entering the text on a new line when it finds a colon. However, it is only doing that for the last colon, not the other colons

```
string list = ":hello:chris:";

void displayEntry(){char *colon = ":";
    for (int i = 0; i<list.length(); i++) {
        char *letter = &list.at(i);
        if (strcmp(letter, colon) != 0) {
            cout << list[i];
            continue;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hint: try printing out `letter`.

Comment: This is one reason `using namespace std;` is bad. Did you know that `list` is in the `std` namespace? While it may not be a problem if not included, this still looks really bad. Plus, `list` is not such a great  variable name.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use `std::string`, and then decide to use 'C' functions such as `strcmp` to determine what the characters are.  What's wrong with sticking with C++?

Answer (score 4):

It's because `strcmp` is not used for comparing single characters, it compares a whole string up until it finds a NUL character.

You don't actually need `char*` for any of this, just use `char` and `==`.

```
if (list.at(i) != ':')
```

Comment: Even better, use `list[i]` rather than `list.at(i)`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Neither is really better than the other, although the bounds-check inside `at` is redundant with the loop-control condition.

Comment: I consider `list[i]` to be better because an exception is not the right tool to catch this kind of error, should it ever happen. It should be a crash, and this is what the implementation may do even with `list[i]`, whereas it is required to throw with `list.at(i)`.

Comment: well I tried both options before but Xcode claims that list[i] is an int whereas ":" is a char*. Thus, it recommended using strcmp instead.

Comment: You aren't looking for strings `":"`, but single characters `':'`.  Use single quotes for characters.